# url regex with unique rules

Tags: javascript, regex

`domain = www.example.xx | example.xx`
I need a regex query with these rules:

- valid domain according to the world domain rules.
- not contain 2 dots in a row.
- not IP \ Ftp.
- at the end :xxxx not allow
- not possible end of domain (.com or .xx.xx) less than 2 digits after .

i'v tried combain input type='url' with this regex:

```
(?=(^[^.]+(?:\.[^.]+)+$))(?=([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?))
```

but it breaks is i add `http:/` or `http:` or add `www.` not 2 digits rule...

Comment: what "not contain 2 dots in a row." means? www.example.net contains 2 dots, isn't it?

Comment: @Isitea 2 dots in a row would be "..", e.g. "www..example.net"

Comment: @MátéSafranka that's what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test following RegEx pattern:

```js
{
  let pattern = /^[^\s]+?(?!\d+)[^.\s]+?(?<!\.[a-zA-Z]{2,2})\.(?!com)([a-zA-Z]{2,3}$)/g;
  function test( string ) {
    console.log( string.match( pattern ) );
  }
  test( `example.org` );
  test( `www.example.net` );
  test( `www.example.nz` );
  test( `12.33.29.24` );
  test( `example.nz` );
  test( `example.com` );
  test( `example.co.kr` );
}
```